# What is the right workflow when applying an update to a git patch back in history

Tags: git, workflow, gerrit

I have submitted a range of patches to a Gerrit server for review and they are all on the same project sequential in time. 
Now someone else has pushed an update to one of the first patches in the sequence and I want to pull it down from gerrit to test.
What are the right steps for doing this?
I know that I could git reset --hard back to just before the patch and then either cherry-pick or repo download each of the patches one by one. Since it is just one patch that have really changed, then I find that a bit overkill.
Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the commit hash of the commit someone made an update to in your history, and checkout to that hash, for example

```
$ git checkout 1358ffb  # use your own hash here
```

then create a branch there and checkout to it

```
$ git checkout -b new_branch
```

Since someone has overwritten your commit with another, we need to replace it. Reset to the parent of the commit.

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Now you can cherry-pick the 'update commit' from gerrit here. Note that this command is just an example, you will need to use your own details and url etc. Basically just copy paste the cherry-pick url from gerrit web UI.

```
$ git fetch ssh://kimusan@example.com:29418/project-name refs/changes/04/104/1 && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
```

Now we need to rebase the other commits back onto this. Checkout master (or whatever is at the top of the tree) and rebase it onto new_branch

```
$ git checkout master
$ git rebase new_branch
```

Git will now place all commits you made after the one you just updated, back on top of it. You can remove new_branch now if you want

```
$ git branch -d new_branch
```